# Have historians offered interpretations on why the disciples claimed they saw a resurrected Jesus?

Tags: religion, historiography, christianity, bible, jesus

It is [generally accepted by historians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Jesus#Two_widely_accepted_historical_facts) who studied the Bible that Jesus almost certainly existed and was crucified. We also know that his disciples claimed Jesus appeared to them after his death.

Have historians offered interpretations on why the disciples claimed they saw a resurrected Jesus? Is there some agreement on these interpretations?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure we can offer much here. Who knows why people claimed they saw a resurrected Jesus? Perhaps they were deceived. Perhaps they were delusional. Perhaps they were outright lying.

Comment: @yannis I'm asking if historians have offered interpretations on this and whether there has been some agreement on these interpretations

Comment: You might want to read the Chapter _Authenticating the Activities of Jesus_ by Craig Evans in the book [Authenticating the Activities of Jesus](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QRP1wF2b2V8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), edited by Bruce D. Chilton & Craig A. Evans

Comment: Wikipedia appears to have an article on this: [Historicity and origin of the Resurrection of Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historicity_and_origin_of_the_Resurrection_of_Jesus#Post-resurrection_appearances)

Comment: In general, I'd also like to suggest to OP that if you're seriously interested in the historicity of the resurrection you're more likely to have luck by hitting the books than relying on forums. Most of the historians and history enthusiasts you can find online tend to shy away from comment on it, for obvious reasons. Those that don't often have a an unusually strong personal stake. This isn't something I have any personal expertise in, but two good points of entry for you might be Bart Ehrman (skeptical) and NT Wright (religious), both respected biblical scholars, and good writers.

Comment: @Era I'm not sure I'd say the Crucifixion is _universally accepted_. Islamic scholars certainly contest it, and at least some historians have pointed out that the Biblical version of the Crucifixion differs in important respects from most other surviving accounts of crucifixion.

Comment: @Era I'd say that the existence of an historical Jesus certainly meets the criterion of embarrassment. I'm less sure about the story of the Crucifixion. I know it appears on most lists, but it's worth reading  [Crucifixion in Antiquity](http://khazarzar.skeptik.net/books/crux002.pdf) by Gunnar Samuelsson (among other studies of crucifixion as a punishment in antiquity), particularly in the context of any discussion of the historicity of the resurrection. As such, I'd agree with Mark the source(s) being referred to by the OP matters in this case.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. Of course, even if it turns out there's good reason to think that the NT description of crucifixion appears inaccurate, I'd still think that could only suggest the narrative(s) of the crucifixion is suspect, rather than the event itself.

Comment: Added a reference for the (accurate) assertion made in the first sentence, and deleted the myriad comments arguing over it.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question which could be answered.

Answer (score 4):

They're not technically Historians, but Social Psychologists certainly have a take on this. In 1956, Leon Festinger et al published a book called When Prophecy Fails.

In a nutshell Festinger and his team heard about a secretive doomsday cult that was awaiting the imminent end of the world. So they joined them to observe how they'd react when the prophecy would fail. They documented two types of behaviors.

Most cults member snapped out of it, with varying degrees of disgruntledness, as you'd expect.

The rest of them did anything but. They basically doubled down, re-interpreting what had just occurred. And went from secretive to full proselyte zealot mode.

(Resemblance with well known resurrection cults is, I am sure, merely coincidental.)

Comment: Thinking about this...its not 100% relevant, but it is to a certain extent. Most scholars will tell you that actually getting crucified must have been a serious blow to a cult claiming that said person was the Messiah, based on the [extant typical Jewish meaning of that word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messiah#Judaism). So looking at what modern cults do with seemingly irreconcilable facts may well be our best possible guide.